# What are some recommendations for guidebooks or companion-books to Heidegger's "Being and Time"?

Tags: ontology, continental-philosophy, heidegger, being-and-time

I'm looking for a guidebook or some other companion to Heidegger's "Being and Time". Ideally, I'd like to find a book that steps through the entire original work, providing summary and background to better understand Heidegger's more technical points throughout this work (no small task, I understand). A little about me - I have a BA in philosophy and quit a MA in the subject to move to computer science, and most of my philosophical background is in the analytic tradition.

One possibility I've found is here: [https://www.amazon.com/Guide-Heideggers-Contemporary-Continental-Philosophy/dp/0791448002](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0791448002)

Is this a decent guidebook? Are there any other recommendations? Thanks.

Comment: Oh man. Good luck. I would recommend reading some Zen texts alongside it. At the end of his life H read Dr. Suzuki and said 'That's what I've been trying to say in my writings'. Or so the story goes.

Comment: "With the philosophy of Nicolai Hartmann we once again enter a world of sober, objective and impartial inquiry, which presses beyond man's self and seeks to grasp the universe of being so far as it is revealed to our limited capacity to know. The basic mood of Existence philosophy, as might be expected, is altogether missing from this universal way of viewing matters. (...).  https://www.ontology.co/hartmannn.htm  I like the use of "existence philosophy" here because it suggests a meager philosophy (existentialism), and not the fullness of being.

Comment: So imo, a philosophy such as Heidegger's is meager, e.g. mere existence, how did we get reduced to this? At this point it might help to read Gyorgy Lukacs' essay on Existentialism at Marxists. Org. (Keep in mind the devastation of WWI.) These two things give a context. As far as actual help with Being and Time, this may shed some light, he is cited by Heidegger, I believe:  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/yorck/

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point out that there's two standard translations of *Being & Time*. One by Maquarrie & Robinson in 1962 and another by Joan Stambaugh in 1996. I found the translation by Joan much the clearer.

I also found *Heidegger: A very short introduction* very useful to set his thinking in context.